# Application of maximum principle for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the heat equation:
$$u_t (x,t) -ku_{xx}(x,t)=0 \quad 0<x<L,0<t$$
$$u(x,0)=\phi(x) \quad 0 \leq x \leq L$$

I want to show that if $\phi(x)=0$ then using the maximum/ minimum principle to show that this will be the trivial solution. I know that we are trying to show that $u(x,t)=0$ whenever $0\leq x\leq L$ and $0\leq t$. I am really unsure how to do this.

I know the maximum principle says that the maximum is attained either at t=0 or on one of the sides $x=0$ or $x=L$.

How can I say that on the sides $x=0$ or $x=L$ it is also zero.

Comment: Do you have boundary conditions for $u$?

Comment: No, I just I have the initial condition nothing else.

Comment: Often with the heat equation we solve "initial / boundary value problems" (aka IBVPs).  I think that without boundary conditions for $u$, the solution to the PDE is not uniquely determined, and not guaranteed to be $0$.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277769/growth-of-tychonovs-counterexample-for-heat-equation-uniqueness . You're not going to get what you want. There the OP cites the famous non-uniqueness result of Tychonov, which is a solution of the heat equation with $0$ initial data on the real line.